# How to iterate over every session in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, session, session-variables

```py
from flask import session
from flask_session import Session
```

`session` always refers to the current visitor's session.  I want to iterate over every session and forcibly log them out (clear their session).

*UNLESS* they have administrator rights (`if session['is_admin'] == True`).

Does `Session` have a list of sessions somewhere?

Comment: What session storage are you using?

Comment: @KlausD. filesystem

Comment: Delete the files! You can also deserialize and evaluate them for selective deletion. See the session code for details.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried `shutil.rmtree('flask_session')` and it deletes the `flask_session` folder and all session files in it.  But, the folder isn't recreated automatically so no new sessions can be created.  So I manually recreate the folder with `os.makedirs('flask_session')` but the supposedly deleted session files are in the new folder somehow, as if the original folder had never been deleted.